# Purpose of button part of a split button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the purpose of the button part of the split button?

I am using the latest version of Bootstrap 3. I have a details split button, when you click on the arrow a couple of options is displayed. When clicked it will take the user to that page. If I click on the button part and not on the arrow what is supposed to happen? Is it supposed to go to a default page? If so how would I change the code below to be able to do this? Do I need to change the button to a link?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Details</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Client Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is "supposed" to happen is up to you. You can definitely make it go to a default page, which could be the same as the 1st dropdown item, or something else. Totally up to you. @Dan's is correct implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use this split button/dropdown to make it easy for a user to access a link without having to open the dropdown.

If you want to change the Button to a link, and keep the styling as is you can simply change the `<button>` to an `<a>` tag.  An `<a>` tag with class `btn btn-default` will be styled like a button.

```
<a href="#your_link" class="btn btn-default">Details</a>
```

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/4Im7S7IQh5)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the button part is to provide the user quick access to a default option. It sounds to me like what you're looking for is a regular dropdown, not a splitbutton. Clicking on a regular dropdown button (anywhere) will open the list of dropdown options to be clicked. Below is a snippet adapted from the Bootstrap docs. [Link to plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hKN3Jb4DBUTbdJZhdFax?p=preview)

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```